# Wordpress, two URLs for the same post

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to have two URL for a same post in wordpress.com?

One would be a short URL like

`http://mydomain.com/28`

and the other will be a SEO friendly one:

`http://mydomain.com/28-this-is-the-post-about...`

thanks

Comment: Is this about programming or configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress, all posts are at the URL mywordpresshome.com/?p=xx where xx is the post ID number. Anything else involves mod_rewrite. WordPress will do one type of rewrite for you in the Admin section -- so you can pick *either* the short version or the long one above. In the Admin interface, it won't let you do both. But you could edit mod_rewrite yourself and effectively get both patterns -- short and long -- to work.

Here's info on mod_rewrite: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings->Permalinks part of the admin panel, you can set the look of your permalinks, but that doesn't mean the default dynamic links (yourblog.com/?p=5 or whatever) will stop working. You can use those links too and they will take you to the corresponding page. However, Wordpress will automatically substitute the dynamic link by its SEO-friendly alias.

I'm not sure whether it's possible to have two different aliases for the same post though.